# CLLocationManager requestLocation button is throwing errors on iOS 15 Xcode 13 Beta 2

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to request one time access to the location. I have made the necessary additions to the info.plist file as shown below:

[image]

Now, when I use the following code to call updateLocation I get the following error:

```
[MKCoreLocationProvider] CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x600001cf4470>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x600002ce03f0> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)
```

I also never got the prompt for allowing the app to use my location.

Here is the complete implementation of the LocationManager class.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion.defaultRegion
    
    static let defaultDistance: CLLocationDistance = 1000000
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func updateLocation() {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: Self.defaultDistance, longitudinalMeters: Self.defaultDistance)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I am using Xcode 13 Beta 2 and running on a simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Do add the request method:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

And to observe authorization status add this delegate method too:

```
extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManager(_
    manager: CLLocationManager,
    didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
      case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        print("Authorized When in Use")
      case .authorizedAlways:
        print("Authorized Always")
      case .denied:
        print("Denied")
      case .notDetermined:
        print("Not determined")
      case .restricted:
        print("Restricted")
      @unknown default:
        print("Unknown status")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error in simulator make sure simulating location is activated

```
Target>Edit Scheme>Run>Options>Allow Location Simulation
```

And

```
Simulator>Features>Location>City Run
```

Comment: I am actually using LocationButton which should pop up the dialog for requiring authentication but it does nothing.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. It could be a number of things

Comment: Are you getting this in simulator?

Comment: I think it has something to do with Beta 2 Xcode 13

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added the CLLocationButton to my child view controller (which also conformed to CLLocationManagerDelegate). In this setup the popup never showed up.

Solution: Adding the button directly to parent view controller **above all other views** solved the issue, popup pops up. Also check that you don't have any warnings in console (e.g. `#locationButton rendering failed due to ...`) - otherwise the button shows normally, but doesn't invoke popup.

Xcode 13 beta 5